# One Bad Sector on new HD

Tags: ssd, bad-sectors

I've bought a new drive (Samsung 840 Pro SSD), and upon connecting it disk-utility is showing it as having one bad sector.  Is that reasonable for a new disk, or should I return it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question which will only resolve in opinion so you may not get a definitive answer. Any way, my definitive answer is get a new one  :)

Answer (score 4):

I would return it while you still can. In my experience when a disk starts getting bad sectors it doesnt last much longer. As @dave said this may differ as each person may have a different opinion but I dont think its worth risking it. I would return

Answer (score 0):

There are many conflicting claims, [some](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/265868-32-ssds-sectors) say that all SSDs come with a few bad blocks and this one is not issue, [others](http://communities.intel.com/thread/23850?start=0&tstart=0) say that one bad block so early is a sign of failure.

I eventually found [this page](http://www.storagesearch.com/bad-blocks-in-ssds.html), which explains these seemingly contradictory results. All SSD's have the ability to recover from a certain number of bad blocks. Each hard drive is different, and initially manufacturers did not allocate enough ability to recover from bad blocks, giving early drives a reputation for unreliability and leading people to state that one bad block was a cause for concern. Eventually, most manufacturers wised up, and started producing drives with enough redundancy, making bad blocks less of a concern.

Given that this is a new drive, there should be many extra sector's available, so while having one bad sector raises the chance of failure slightly, it isn't enough to worry about. I would check your new drive in a month and replace your drive only if you see the number of bad sectors growing.

Finally, no matter how reliable your drives are, you should always make backups of your data.